# Why does entry point of _start results in error when linking with GCC on Windows/MinGW?

Tags: windows, gcc, assembly, nasm

> Why does entry point of _start results in error when linking with GCC on Windows/MinGW?

Using the following .asm file I assemble and link using the following commands on Windows 10 using MinGW:

```
nasm -f win32 helloworld.asm
gcc -e_start -o helloworld helloworld.obj
```

Assembling works just fine, however linking produces the following error:

```
c:/dev/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

Changing `_start` to `_main` everything seems to work fine. Why is that?

```
BITS 32

    global _start
    extern _printf

    section .text
_start:
    push msg
    call _printf
    add esp, 4
    ret
msg:
    db "HelloWorld", 10, 0
```

Comment: Can you show your source code?

Comment: The source code is already in the question. It is the .asm code you see.

Comment: Then why did you mark it C++?

Comment: Try -nodefaultlibs

Comment: What is your argument for doing this :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you link with `gcc`, not the linker `ld`. Gcc is wrapper for many compilers and preprocessors and assembler and linker. Ie. it helps to automate many things.

Like for example linking object files together with default C startup code, without explicitly asking for it.

The init startup code already has `_start` label, and after initializing stdlib C environment, it will call `main`.

So if you link with stdlib, you have to provide `main`, if you put -nodefaultlibs as linking option, it will link together only the `.o` files specified explicitly. Then your `_start` is the only one defined.

Comment: Why don't GCC also complain that it sees two _start labels?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen
I'm not sure, try to add global `main:` (just empty stub) a keep `_start` also, to see how the output will come. I think two _start may produce only linking warning with *some* binary result (not error). In case of multiple .o redefining the same symbol, I think the first file wins, but I'm just guessing, I always just fixed my linking and never really bothered what happens with redefinitions.