# How to write _start function to call the main function in C

Tags: c, windows, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly

By using inline assembly asm volatile, how can I implement _start function in C which can call the main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
```

I tried alot, but it didn't work at all, and I'm a beginner in inline asm.

I tried this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}

void _start()
{
    int argc;
    char **argv, **envp;
    int ret = 0;
    asm volatile(
        "mov %%edi, %0\n\t"
        "mov %%esi, %1\n\t"
        "mov %%edx, %2\n\t"
        : "=m"(argc), "=m"(argv), "=m"(envp)
    );
    asm volatile(
        "mov %0, %%edi\n\t"
        "mov %1, %%esi\n\t"
        "mov %2, %%edx\n\t"
        "call _main\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %%ebx\n\t"
        :
        : "g"(argc), "g"(argv), "g"(envp), "g"(ret)
        : "%edi", "%esi", "%edx", "%ebx"
    );
    asm volatile(
        "mov %0, %%edi\n\t"
        "mov $60, %%eax\n\t"
        "syscall"
        :
        : "g"(ret)
    );
}
```

It's working on Windows, but not on Linux Ubuntu, so how can I fix that please?

Comment: `__main()` perhaps. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Initialization.html.  calling `printf()` without initialising the standard library may not work however.

Comment: @Clifford well, then how can I call the main function without printf? Just return 0 inside the main function.

Comment: That is not the point.  If you are going to customize the CRT start-up, you become responsible for all the initialisation of the C runtime environment.  It is not just a matter of calling main.  If that were the case, the start would be main, not _start. I don't know about an OS hosted environment (or why you would do this in such a system) but in an embedded system (where this is common), _start would be responsible for creating a stack, static initialisation and library initialisation. For a hosted environment, all that may be performed by the OS loader, so I may be wrong.

Comment: I'm working on windows

Comment: Ok. If it works it works.  Begs the question of why you might do this?

Comment: @Clifford no it didn't work

Comment: What didn't work? __main or printf?  Check the link map to find the symbol used for main.  It is not uncommon to add underscores - may be single rather than a double.  Or for __main to be a different function that initialis s the library then calls main().

Comment: How are you linking? This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683721/why-does-entry-point-of-start-results-in-error-when>linking-with-gcc-on-windows.  Also suggests single underscore `_main`.

Comment: Also what toolchain are you using.  _start may not even be the correct entrypoint according to https://nullprogram.com/blog/2016/01/31/

Comment: @Clifford it's working on windows but not on Linux, what to do please?

Comment: Windows and Linux have different function-calling conventions and different process-startup ABIs.  The same asm can't be portable between two systems, unless it figures out which it's running on and branches.  Your `main` doesn't use its `argc` and `argv` args, otherwise you'd have realized that this doesn't work on Windows either.  `_start` would need to be `__attribute__((naked))` at least, otherwise compiler-generated code might use registers for something before your asm.

Comment: Or just for fun, I convinced GCC to compile a C function into a valid `_start` for the x86-64 System V ABI (Linux). [How to get arguments value in \_start and call main() using inline assembly in C, without Glibc or CRT start files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50260855)  Other answers show more sane code using hand-written asm. (`asm` statements at global scope, or a `naked` function)

Comment: @Clifford: In a dynamically-linked Linux executable, glibc gets itself initialized by having its init functions registered to be run by the dynamic linker.  A statically-linked executable will indeed crash if you call `call printf` or `malloc` from `_start` without having first manually called the glibc init functions that CRT startup code calls.  I don't know much about Windows C libraries.  A few DLLs are mapped into every user-space process whether it asks for them or not, so I think you can call GetStdHandle and WriteFile without any extra init or linking. The OS creates the stack for you.